# Regex: Find newline if

Tags: regex, replace, find, sublimetext3

I want to find those newline only, more specific if word is not ending with dot or some other punctuation marks

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `(?<![:punct:])\n` to match newlines not preceeded by a punctuation character.